# Is the Faraday effect absent in vacuum?

Tags: electromagnetism

Faraday effect is the rotation of the plane of polarization  of a light beam by a magnetic field. Is it absent in vacuum?

[image]

Comment: The Faraday effect is, by definition, an effect that happens in matter. Are you asking if there is a vacuum Faraday effect? If there is, it's most likely not measurable in the lab on visible light. I don't know if there are QFT interaction terms that could be interpreted as the equivalents of a Faraday effect and what it would take to see them in high energy systems.

Comment: I’m asking if the same rotation effect from magnetic field happens on light in vacuum.

Comment: Certainly not on a scale that is detectable by any imaginable means. In the low energy regime (visible photons and static fields) the self-interaction of the electromagnetic field is extremely small. There are such interactions at extremely high energies, but I can't tell you whether they could amount to something like a Faraday effect like rotation.

Answer (score 2):

There is no Faraday effect in a vacuum. The Faraday effect results from the permeability of the medium being a skew-symmetric tensor generated by the bias field, $\mu_0$ is a scalar independent of the fields.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions of Maxwell's equations in a vacuum, where there are no sources, are amenable to linear superposition, so you can add a static magnetic field to a plane wave/wave packet with no effect. Axion production notwithstanding.